# Error using System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda

Tags: c#, lambda

Im getting the following runtime error trying to use Dynamic expressions to parse
a constructed Lambda statement.

> An exception of type 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException' occurred in
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: No property or field 't' exists in type 'MessageText'

```
 public static void ApplyAttributeRules<T>(this EntityTypeConfiguration<T> entity) where T : BaseObject

// logic that determines the propertyName ....
var propLambda = // this line fails
   System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<T, String>("t=>t." + PropertyName); //
```

The Type T was MessageText.    Im trying to build the lambda expression

```
t=>t.PropName
```

clearly I dont understand the Docu http://www.lcs.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/handouts/CoreTechnologies/CSharp/samples/CSharpSamples/LinqSamples/DynamicQuery/Dynamic%20Expressions.html

can anyone explain how I should call ParseLambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to resharper Decompile sources...

```
var propLambda = 
System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<T, String>("t=>t." + PropertyName);
```

I found a option that works.

```
var propLambda = 
System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<T, String>(PropertyName);
```

The Identity x=>x.   is added when only a property is supplied.
Not sure I want to learn this API :-) But I do like the concept...